# Spring MVC - REST Get Method with RequestParam List<String>

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

If I have a controller interface like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{CustomerId}/audit")
public @ResponseBody Long countAudit(
   @PathVariable(value = "CustomerId") String customerId,
   @RequestParam(value = "Users", required = false) List<String> users)
```

And I use RestTemplate to make a call, via getForObject, like so:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
users.add("Bill");
users.add("John");
String customerId = "1234";
Long cnt = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Long.class, customerId, users);
```

Why does the first item in the List on the controller side, have a [ in front, while the last item has the matching ]?

On the client.. it looks like this:  "Bill", "John"
on the controller(server), it looks like this:  "[Bill", "John]"

Any ideas, and is there a way around this or to deal with this?  Any other suggestions on how to pass a List<> via requestParam in resttemplate?   Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 0):

The server side is not correct parsing the json format. Instead of parsing it, the server gives you the json string (`["Bill", "John"]`) of the complete message.

I can not tell you why the server is not parsing it correctly, but I hope that hint helps you to find the problem.

Comment: Hmm.. very interesting.. That does provide me a clue.. as I have not yet worked with JSON, I did not realize that was json format.  Thank you very much.